# c++ change an object value in another class

Tags: c++

I'd like to change the object `brain` in class `Robot`, not in `main` function. But the `brain.brainData = 11;` gives me an error:

```
class_constructor_another.C:11:3: error: ‘brain’ does not name a type
   brain.brainData = 11; //something wrong
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
class RobotBrain{ 
public: 
  int brainData = 10;
  void process() { std::cout<<"Do some process"<<std::endl; } 
}; 
 
class Robot{ 
public:
  RobotBrain brain;
  brain.brainData = 11; //something wrong
  void processInformation(){ 
    brain.process(); 
  }
  
}; 
 
int main() 
{ 
  Robot myRobot; 
  myRobot.processInformation();
  myRobot.brain.brainData = 12; //this works
  std::cout<<myRobot.brain.brainData<<std::endl;
  
}
```

Comment: `brain.brainData = 11; //something wrong` doesn't make sense in the class declaration. It belongs in a constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do inline member initialization in a procedural way like you're attempting.  You must either define a constructor for `RobotBrain` that initializes the value, or a constructor for `Robot` that performs the non-encapsulated approach you're doing.

Option A:

```
class RobotBrain { 
public: 
  int brainData = 10;
  RobotBrain() = default; // (optional)
  RobotBrain(int bd) : brainData(bd) {}
}; 
 
class Robot { 
public:
  RobotBrain brain{11};
};
```

Option B:

```
class RobotBrain { 
public: 
  int brainData = 10;
}; 
 
class Robot { 
public:
  RobotBrain brain;
  Robot() {
    brain.brainData = 11;
  }
};
```